# asible variable constructed of vars as a volume

Tags: ansible

Hello im working with ansible and in my docker container task im trying to set my volumes as a var.

Here is my volumes var

```
volumes_map: |
      - "{{ airflow_script_location }}:{{ airflow_script_location_in_container }}:ro"
      - "{{ airflow_data_input_location }}:{{ airflow_data_input_location_in_container }}:rw"
      - "{{ airflow_data_output_success_location }}:{{ airflow_data_output_success_location_in_container }}:rw"
      - "{{ airflow_data_output_failed_location }}:{{ airflow_data_output_failed_location_in_container }}:rw"
      - "{{ airflow_root_location }}/requirements.txt:/requirements.txt"
      - "{{ airflow_services_location }}/:{{ airflow_services_location_in_container }}:rw"
      - "{{ airflow_root_location }}/airflow.cfg:{{ airflow_root_in_container }}/airflow.cfg"
      - "{{ airflow_logs_location }}:{{ airflow_logs_location_in_container }}"
      - "{{ airflow_conf_location}}:{{ airflow_conf_location_in_container }}"
```

and this is how im setting it in my volumes  but this isnt working

```
volumes: "{{ volumes_map }}"
```

When i set the volumes directly without using the volumes_map it all works.

Answer (score 1):

## Try to Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) module

## The "volumes_map" type is List,you can try

```
- debug: msg="{% for item in volumes_map %}{{item}}{% endfor %}"
```

## Use Map it may help

```
- name: test
  shell: echo "{{item}}"
  with_items:
      - "{{ airflow_script_location }}:{{ airflow_script_location_in_container }}:ro"
      - "{{ airflow_root_location }}/airflow.cfg:{{ airflow_root_in_container }}/airflow.cfg"
      - "{{ airflow_conf_location}}:{{ airflow_conf_location_in_container }}"
  register: volumes_map

- debug: var=volumes_map.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but templates is not what im trying to use... i wanto set the variable "{{ volumes_map }}" list as my volumes .. i tried something like this but no luck yet:

  volumes:
      - "{% for item in volumes_map %}{{item}}{% endfor %}"

Comment: Also tried this today 
**
volumes: "{{ items }}"
with_items:
- "{{ volume_map}}"
**